# Function returning Deferred with a name that does not end with async

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am trying to learn Kotlin coroutines recently I have noticed that in case of map that returns bunch of `async` IDE is displaying message saying that `Function returning Deferred with a name that does not end with async`. This is the code I have

```
runBlocking {
    try {
        val siteDeferred = async { getSite(order) }
        // Place where I get warning-----------| (Function returning Deferred with a name that does not end with Async)
        //                                     v
        val orderLineDeferred = order.line.map { async { getOrderDetail(it) } }

        // Place where I get warning-------------------| (Function returning Deferred with a name that does not end with Async)
        //                                             v
        val orderLineProductsDeferred = order.line.map { async { getOrderProductInformation(it.productId) } }

        val site = siteDeferred.await()
        val orderLine = orderLineDeferred.awaitAll()
        val orderLineProducts = orderLineProductsDeferred.awaitAll()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        throw Exception(e.message)
    }
}

private suspend getOrderDetail(OrderLine orderLine): OrderDetail...
private suspend getSite(Order order): Site ...
private suspend getOrderProductInformation(String productId): Product ...
```

Am I missing anything here. Furthermore, I would like to know whether this is the right way to do exception handling or not and is there a way to clean up `try` block so that I can get the value directly even if that means I will have to use `async` in other methods.

Comment: Are your suspend functions returning a Deferred?

Comment: No I am not returning deferred

Comment: Just disable the warning. It doesn't apply to you. You might also open a Kotlin issue because it shouldn't issue this warning for a generic type that just happens to be `Deferred` in a specific case.

Answer (score 5):

function *getSite()* renamed to *getSiteAsync()*，Others functions are modified in this way.

Comment: We name such functions with the "…Async" suffix to highlight the fact that they only start asynchronous computation and one needs to use the resulting deferred value to get the result.